# Javascript - Strip HTML tags and their contents from a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Let's say we have this string

```
Required Field <em>*</em>
```

How do I strip this string (in javascript) to be left with

```
Required Field
```

Comment: There are millions of posts and dozens of SO topics about the fact that HTML processing with regular expressions (without callbacks / regex extensions) is a terrible idea.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question, I found the other duplicate questions' answers to be lacking. They'd remove the other HTML tags, but not the contents inside the tags. Here's what I ended up doing, but I don't feel good about it:

Comment: $('.parent-element').clone().children().remove().end().html()